# numpy.test fails with FAIL: test_error_message (test_utils.TestEqual)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Python so fingers crossed this is a simple error!

When running the following code from an anaconda prompt I get an error;

```
python -c "import numpy; numpy.test()"
```

The error message is;

```
FAIL: test_error_message (test_utils.TestEqual)
```

More information that's way over my head;

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda22\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\tests\test_utils.py", line 272, in test_error_message
    "\nArrays are not equal\n\n"
AssertionError: '\nArrays are not equal\n\n(shapes (2L,), (1L, 2L) mismatch)\n x: array([1, 2])\n y: [repr failed for <matrix>: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()]' != '\nArrays are not equal\n\n(shapes (2,), (1, 2) mismatch)\n x: array([1, 2])\n y: [repr failed for <matrix>: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()]'
```

I literally have no idea how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I'm not sure why this worked but I uninstalled Numpy using;

```
conda uninstall numpy
```

Then reinstalled numpy with;

```
conda install numpy
```

Then reinstalled all the packages that were uninstalled when numpy was uninstalled;

```
conda install astropy bottleneck dask datashape distributed h5py matplotlib numba numexpr numpy odo pandas patsy pygpu pytables pywavelets scikit-image scikit-learn scipy seaborn statsmodels theano
```

Bingo bango, no more failures!